# No schema when creating Sheets-based external table from command line

Tags: google-bigquery

Having found that for one specific sheets document I was trying to reference as an external table, the heading row was being included in the data when executing queries*. I decided to drop the table and recreate it using a definitions file which would definitely expose the options from the docs. It didn't seem to work as no schema is created, despite being defined in the file.

I've recreated the issue with a simple sheet with 3 columns and a frozen header row and the following test.def file:

```
{
  "autodetect": false,
  "schema": {
    "fields": [
      {"name": "c1", "type": "STRING", "mode": "nullable"},
      {"name": "c2", "type": "STRING", "mode": "nullable"},
      {"name": "c3", "type": "STRING", "mode": "nullable"},
    ]
  },
  "sourceFormat": "GOOGLE_SHEETS", 
  "sourceUris": [
    "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/..."
  ],
  "googleSheetsOptions": {
    "skipLeadingRows": 1
  }
}
```

and then I try to create the file using:

```
bq mk myproject:mydataset.mytable < test.def
```

the table is created but no schema is present - what am I doing wrong?

- this issue remains but I cannot identify why 95% of the time the table is created OK and the first/header row correctly excluded from the data returned by a query but in one specific case, created the same way as all others, the header row is returned in the data ...

Odd :(

M

Answer (score 1):

OK so the correct syntax is:

```
bq mk --external_table_definition=myfile.def project:dataset.table
```

This also allows you to tell google to skip leading rows on the sheet (as of tiem of writing not possible from BQ UI)

M